# python apply function to df pandas - atribute error

Tags: python, function, pandas, attributes, apply

I have a data frame "b" with numbers stored as text like '12.5%'. 
One column is:

```
1       NaN
2       NaN
3      1.2%
4      0.6%
5       NaN
6      1.4%
7      0.1%
8       NaN
9      5.1%
10     2.5%
11    89.1%
12      NaN
Name: Idaho, dtype: object
```

I've wrote a function to apply to each column:

```
def sinPorc(tbl):
    return float(tbl.replace('%', ''))
```

but when I try to apply it I get:

```
b.Idaho.apply(sinPorc)
```

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

I 've also created an example table, and apply the function but in this case worked:

```
ejemplo=pd.DataFrame({'A':['1.3%', 'NaN'],
              'B':['1.3%', '0.7%']})

ejemplo.A.apply(sinPorc)
```

and I got the expected result:

```
    1.3
    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

I don't know why I cannot apply the function to the original table. What might be the problem and what should I do to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `float(str(tbl).replace('%', ''))` in the `def` function.You need to cast your row elements as  `string` for the `replace` to work.

Comment: Thanks @NickilMaveli, it's ok. I don't understand why the original function worked in the 2nd table, without needing this.

Comment: Sounds like the column already contains float values. I tried to replicate with the values as string type and then as float types. It might be helpful to debug by typing `type(b.Idaho[0])`, assuming index 0 has a value that isnt `NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original method didn't work because NaN was not a string, but the float value `np.NaN`

Try this...

```
np.NaN.replace('%', '')
```

and you will get the same error.

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

You could change `sinPorc` to

```
def sinPorc(tbl):
    if tbl is np.NaN:
        return tbl
    else:
        return float(tbl.replace('%', ''))
```

Which will preserver your `NaN` values which are useful for other Pandas functionality, or you could force the value to a string like Nickil mentioned in the comments.

```
float(str(tbl).replace('%', ''))
```